# How to turn $(n+1)^2$ to $n^2(1+\frac{1}{n})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the intermediate steps to turn $(n+1)^2$ to $n^2(1+\frac{1}{n})^2$? Is there a formula for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "turn"? They are not equal: for example, if $n = 0$, the first is $1$, and the second is $0$.

Comment: You're missing a power of two on the second term. This technique is called factoring.

Comment: @mihaild: Um, no. The second is undefined.

Comment: @TedShifrin *Indeterminate. $0\cdot\infty$ is a canonical indeterminate form.

Comment: @DonThousand Well, the expression $0^2(1+\frac{1}{0})^2$ is an indeterminate form, but all the same, it's also an undefined expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean $n^2(1+\frac 1n)^2$, of course. Provided $n\ne 0$,

$$(n+1)^2 = \big(n(1+\frac 1n)\big)^2 = n^2(1+\frac 1n)^2.$$

Comment: I am wondering why substituting zero for $n$ on the left side results in 1 but on the right hand-side results in (....)?  In other words, is using $'='$ correct in this case? Of course this is not related to this specific answer.

Comment: This algebraic manipulation is only valid when $n\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

$(n+1)=n(1+\frac{1}{n})$  Square both sides.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)^2 & = \bigg(\frac{n+1}{1}\bigg)^2\\
& = \bigg(\frac{n}{n}\cdot\frac{n+1}{1}\bigg)^2\\
& = \bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{n\cdot 1}\bigg)^2\\
& = \bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{1\cdot n}\bigg)^2\\
& = \bigg(\frac{n}{1}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}\bigg)^2\\
& = \bigg(n\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)\bigg)^2\\
& = n^2\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^2\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Equivalently, $$(1+ \frac{1}{n})^2= 1+ \frac{2}{n}+ n^2$$ so $$n^2(1+ \frac{1}{n})^2= n^2(1+ \frac{2}{n}+ \frac{1}{n^2})= n^2+ 2n+ 1= (n+ 1)^2$$.